# How to make a view like MIUI-ROM's preference view?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, preferences

has anyone been using the MIUI-Rom? 
I think its UI is pretty good.
And I wondered how they make it?

Basically, I think it's a preference. 
But how to separate the preference view into several section with a header for each?

Here is a picture to give you a direct view.

[image]

Please, help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it By Using Segment Radio Button.

See [this Example](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton). for your sollution and set the custom view as u need. If it not works for you then let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: em...well,I've known the Radio things before I ask the question, what I wanna know is the preference below, How can I supply the same theme(I don't know if it's a theme problem, just guess)?Don't let me use the xml to put thoes item one by one...I know how to do that, but it brings a lot of problem..e.g. I want to redo several items or change their position, that would be very difficult to do.. Thanks